# Travelling & working with recepisse for Carte de sejour 2eme demande

Tags: working-visas, france, netherlands, students, residence-cards

I'm a student of Indian origin studying in Paris, France. My carte de sejour is going to expire on 6 Dec 2018 & I've applied for renewal. I've received the recepisse. This is my 2nd request for carte de sejour. My recepisse expire in June 2019.

I have an internship in the Netherlands from January to March 2019. This internship is necessary for me to complete my course. In case I do not receive my carte de sejour by the time my internship begins, is it legal for me to travel & work in the Netherlands with my recepisse?

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge you are will be legally staying in the Netherlands only with a valid French residence permit.

I don't know how they will handle working for your internship, most probably they will treat you as French tax subject and they will pay to your French bank account the salary. I don't think you can work with French residence permit unless it is EU blue card.

So while you don't have residence permit on your hands you should have French visa in the passport to freely travel within the EU. At least this is how things are handled in the Netherlands.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your institute of study or internship host will help you take care of this

Adding to @EugenMartnov's valid [answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/15164/7110):

You are one of many many students in the same situation. I'm certainly this will be legal. However - there could be some sort of procedure involved to clear your stay with the relevant Dutch authorities, or alternatively to provide you with some certificate or residence permit stick, etc.

Now, it is either:

1. Your French university/institute of study, or
2. The Dutch entity at which you will be interning

who have this procedure set up. You should contact both, and ask about such a procedure. Either they help you, or they tell you that nothing is necessary and you can just go on your internship.